# nginx named regular expression

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'd like to catch a part of the server_name to route an old domain to a new one like:

```
server {
    server_name   "~^(?<domain>)\.v1.+$";

    location / {
        proxy_pass       https://$domain.v2.com/;
        proxy_set_header Host            $domain.v2.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `domain` variable is empty an nginx tries to resolve `.v2.com`.
I'd like to catch everything from the `server_name` which is before `.v1` and write it to the `proxy_pass`.

Comment: Try: `server_name ~^(?<domain>.*)\.v1;`

Comment: Thx it's working!